# Create event (dummy) one year before/ after of a dummy variable (or close to)

Tags: r, date, dummy-variable, panel-data

I am doing an event study in an unbalanced panal data set. The basic structure is that I have a different number of observations (deliveries) for each firm at different points over a period of around 15 years. I am interested in an event (price increase) which is coded as a dummy variable if it occurs and some dummy lead and lags to check if the effect of the price increase on my dependent variable becomes apparent around that event. As an example, for some firms the price increase occurs at 5 deliveries of e.g. 50 over 15 years.

However, now I also want to "simulate" the same event study one year after and before to improve inference. So I want R to duplicate the event dummy for each firm at the delivery closest to one year before and after. The delivery dates occur not daily but on average every 25 days.

So, as code, the data looks something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(firm_id = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4),
                   delivery_id = c(1,2,6,9,15,3,5,18,4,7,8,10,11,13,17,19,22,12,14,16,20,21),
                   date=c("2004-06-16", "2004-08-12", "2004-11-22", "2005-07-03", "2007-01-04",
                          "2004-09-07", "2005-02-01", "2006-01-17", 
                          "2004-10-11", "2005-02-01", "2005-04-27", "2005-06-01", "2005-07-01",
                          "2006-01-03", "2007-01-06", "2007-03-24", "2007-05-03", 
                          "2005-08-03", "2006-02-19", "2006-06-13", "2007-02-04", "2007-04-26"),
                   price_increase = c(0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                   price_increase_year_before = c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                   price_increase_year_afer = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))
```

Creating

```
     firm_id delivery_id  date     price_increase  price_increase_year_before   price_increase_year_after
1        1           1 2004-06-16              0                          1                        0
2        1           2 2004-08-12              0                          0                        0
3        1           6 2004-11-22              0                          0                        0
4        1           9 2005-07-03              1                          0                        0
5        1          15 2007-01-04              0                          0                        0
6        2           3 2004-09-07              0                          0                        0
7        2           5 2005-02-01              0                          0                        0
8        2          18 2006-01-17              0                          0                        0
9        3           4 2004-10-11              0                          0                        0
10       3           7 2005-02-01              0                          1                        0
11       3           8 2005-04-27              0                          0                        0
12       3          10 2005-06-01              0                          0                        0
13       3          11 2005-07-01              0                          0                        0
14       3          13 2006-01-03              1                          0                        0
15       3          17 2007-01-06              0                          0                        1
16       3          19 2007-03-24              0                          0                        0
17       3          22 2007-05-03              0                          0                        0
18       3          12 2005-08-03              0                          0                        0
19       4          14 2006-02-19              0                          0                        0
20       4          16 2006-06-13              0                          0                        0
21       4          20 2007-02-04              0                          0                        0
22       4          21 2007-04-26              0                          0                        0
```

Where I want to create the two dummy columns on the right based on the price_increase and the date, for each firm. Although I would start with dyplr's `group_by` and `mutate` approach and an `if_else` function, I have no idea how to create a condition that becomes `TRUE` when a delivery in one year is +1/-1 month close to the date in the prior or following year and how to select the respective delivery. Do you guys have an idea?

Comment: Why is there only one 1 in `price_increase_year_after` ? Also the data you have shared seems incomplete. Can you correct that?

Comment: Hi Ronak, thank you for your comment. The reason is because one year after the price increase for `firm_id = 1` , the next delivery (`delivery_id = 15`) is two years later which is outside the range of one year +1/-1 month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible approach using `dplyr`.

After `group_by(firm_id)`, `filter` and include groups where there was a price increase.

Then, create your two dummy variables if the date is one year (+/- 30 days) before or after the date where the `price_increase` was equal to 1. Then, would `filter` for rows that met these criteria.

Using `distinct` you can prevent multiples or duplicates for your dummy variable within a group/firm. Otherwise, if your deliveries were 25 days apart, it seemed like a theoretical possibility.

The rest afterwards is joining back to the original data, replacing the `NA` with zero for dummy columns, and sorting.

```
library(dplyr)

df$date <- as.Date(df$date)

df %>%
  group_by(firm_id) %>%
  filter(any(price_increase == 1)) %>%
  mutate(
    price_increase_year_before = ifelse(
      between(date[price_increase == 1] - date, 335, 395), 1, 0),
    price_increase_year_after = ifelse(
      between(date - date[price_increase == 1], 335, 395), 1, 0),
    ) %>%
  filter(price_increase_year_before == 1 | price_increase_year_after == 1) %>%
  distinct(firm_id, price_increase_year_before, price_increase_year_after, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
  right_join(df) %>%
  replace_na(list(price_increase_year_before = 0, price_increase_year_after = 0)) %>%
  arrange(firm_id, date)
```

**Output**

```
   firm_id delivery_id date       price_increase price_increase_year_before price_increase_year_after
     <dbl>       <dbl> <date>              <dbl>                      <dbl>                     <dbl>
 1       1           1 2004-06-16              0                          1                         0
 2       1           2 2004-08-12              0                          0                         0
 3       1           6 2004-11-22              0                          0                         0
 4       1           9 2005-07-03              1                          0                         0
 5       1          15 2007-01-04              0                          0                         0
 6       2           3 2004-09-07              0                          0                         0
 7       2           5 2005-02-01              0                          0                         0
 8       2          18 2006-01-17              0                          0                         0
 9       3           4 2004-10-11              0                          0                         0
10       3           7 2005-02-01              0                          1                         0
11       3           8 2005-04-27              0                          0                         0
12       3          10 2005-06-01              0                          0                         0
13       3          11 2005-07-01              0                          0                         0
14       3          12 2005-08-03              0                          0                         0
15       3          13 2006-01-03              1                          0                         0
16       3          17 2007-01-06              0                          0                         1
17       3          19 2007-03-24              0                          0                         0
18       3          22 2007-05-03              0                          0                         0
19       4          14 2006-02-19              0                          0                         0
20       4          16 2006-06-13              0                          0                         0
21       4          20 2007-02-04              0                          0                         0
22       4          21 2007-04-26              0                          0                         0
```

Comment: thank you for your solution. It does exactly what I planned (and you are absolutely right with the `distinct` part. I found a way yet much less elegant, since I did not know you could calculate this simply in the `as.Date` class. Big thanks!